# How to tell if it is the first time that a process starts or not

Tags: c, linux

I am working on a program by C that some processes need to access a shared memory on an embed linux. This shared memory needs to be initialized when it was created. Any process attaching to this memory may crash. When it restarted (may be by linux INIT), it must not initialize the shared memory again since other processes are using it. How to tell if current starting of the process that is creating shared memory is the first time or restarted. I came up with an idea that allocates a integer in shared memory where will be written as a number like 5678956 (any number other than ffffffff or 00000000) to claim this memory has been initialized. But I am not sure if this is working well since the critical data is storing this memory. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use both a shared semaphore and shared memory segment. Attempt opening the semaphore with `sem_open` using `O_EXCL|O_CREAT` and an initial value of 0. If that succeeds, create and initialize the shared memory segment, then post the semaphore and close it. If opening the seamphore in exclusive mode failed, open it non-exclusive and wait on the semaphore, then close it.

Another solution, if you prefer: Use a named file in the filesystem with `mmap` and `MAP_SHARED` for your shared memory. First create the file with a temporary name and populate it with the initial data it should contain. Then attempt to `link` it to the real name. If `link` fails with `EEXIST`, you're not the first process, and you can just delete your temp file and open and map the existing one. If `link` succeeds, you are the first process.

Comment: You can even create the named file in a `tmpfs` filesystem so it doesn't touch a physical disk.

Comment: Yes, it's actually rather frustrating that POSIX specified the ugly `shm_open` interface rather than defining `/dev/shm` with normal filesystem semantics. Being unable to `rename`/`link` shared memory objects makes them much less useful than they would otherwise be.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers. You enlightened me to use excl|IPC_CREAT to create shared memory and initialize it directly, instead of using semaphore. It works fine so far. Do you have any idea if there is anything potential issue on this? Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, there's a fundamental race condition with just using exclusive create on the shared memory segment. The second process might start after the first process has created the shared memory segment, but before it has initialized the contents of it. The only ways around this are to either implement your own synchronization object (with atomics) where the "zero state" is a valid initialized state, or to use a secondary synchronization object (like filesystem names or a named semaphore) outside of the shared memory object.

Comment: Thanks for comments. But I am still a little bit confused. The condition I set for initializing the share memory is only creating shared memory with EXCL|CREAT. If failed, it will shmget again only with 0666|CREAT this time. How the second process can meet this condition to init the shared memory when it start after the first one creating shm but before the first one init it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean there is a possible race that makes two process enter the condition shmget(id, ... EXCL|CREATE) at the same time, then both two processes initialize the shared memory to mess it up?

Comment: I described the exact race. If instance 2 starts after instance 1 creates the shared memory object, but before instance 1 initializes the contents, then instance 2 may or may not be able to detect this condition, but **it has no way to wait** for instance 1 to finish initializing the shared memory before proceeding.

Comment: More things :). In your first answer, what is "open,post and close semaphore"? Is it respectively mapping to semget(key,...EXCL|CREAT) and semop("-1" P operation) and semop(+1 V operation) [not exact parameters,sorry]? "close it"means V operation semop(+1)? or delete it? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for not voting your great answer before.